# How to put Gridview closer to Card widget in Column widget

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to create a user interface for my app. I need to design like this:

[image]

But my recent UI looks like this:

[image]

In second screenshot I scrolled down because my gridview widget (which has 4 card widgets) doesn't come closer to other widgets. The other widgets are: a widget for titlebar, a card widget which has a graph and subgraph widgets. I put titlebar and graphs card widget inside a stack for showing them above. I put these two combined widgets inside a column with my gridview widget. And I wrap this column widget with a SingleChildScrollView widget because I want my page to be scrollable. **So my questions is this: How I can put my gridview widget closer to my card widget as in the first image ?**

Here is the code that I used for this UI:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_circular_chart/flutter_circular_chart.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'baskana_rapor_icon_icons.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Widget> widgets = new List();
  List<CircularSegmentEntry> dataList = _loadData();
  int _totalCount;
  Widget s1, s2, total;
  final formatter = new NumberFormat("#,##");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widgets.add(_buildBody(context));

    return Scaffold(body: _buildBody(context));
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  ),
                  _buildTitleBar(context),
                  Positioned(bottom: 65, left: 35, child: _buildCard(context)),
                ],
              ),
              _buildGridButtons(context),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGridButtons(BuildContext context) {
    int itemWidth = 80;
    int itemHeight = 40;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            primary: true,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/MahalleRapor');
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(25),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            BaskanaRaporIcon.mahalle_raporu,
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Mahalle Raporu',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 0,
                        right: 1,
                        left: 1,
                        child: Divider(
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                          endIndent: 45,
                          indent: 50,
                          thickness: 3,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/BirimRapor');
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(25),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            BaskanaRaporIcon.birim_raporu,
                            color: Colors.green[300],
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Birim Raporu',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 0,
                        right: 1,
                        left: 1,
                        child: Divider(
                          color: Colors.green[300],
                          endIndent: 45,
                          indent: 50,
                          thickness: 3,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/GelirGider');
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(25),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            BaskanaRaporIcon.gelir_gider,
                            color: Colors.yellow[700],
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Gelir / Gider',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 0,
                        right: 1,
                        left: 1,
                        child: Divider(
                          color: Colors.yellow[700],
                          endIndent: 45,
                          indent: 50,
                          thickness: 3,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/BaskanaMesaj');
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(25),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            BaskanaRaporIcon.baskana_msg,
                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Başkana Mesaj',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 0,
                        right: 1,
                        left: 1,
                        child: Divider(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          endIndent: 45,
                          indent: 50,
                          thickness: 3,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // ignore: todo
  //TODO: Better implementation of UI
  final double buttonHeight = 50;

  Widget _buildCard(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 500 + buttonHeight,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: [
            Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 0.5),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .65,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Genel Durum",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          letterSpacing: 0.3,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      thickness: 0.3,
                      endIndent: 10,
                      indent: 10,
                    ),
                    _buildChart(dataList),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    _buildSubGraph(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              //top: -buttonHeight /2,
              bottom: 27,
              child: _buildDetailsButton(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDetailsButton(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      height: 50,
      minWidth: 100,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/DetailPage');
        },
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
        child: Text("Detayları Gör"),
      ),
    );
  }

  Row _buildSubGraph() {
    String s1 = formatter.format((dataList[1].value / _totalCount) * 100);
    String s0 = formatter.format((dataList[0].value / _totalCount) * 100);

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Column(
          //İşlemde
          children: [
            Text(
              dataList[1].rankKey,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: dataList[1].color,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
              height: 50,
              width: 150,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '${dataList[1].value.toInt()}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                      '%' + s1,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          //Sonuçlanan
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text(
              dataList[0].rankKey,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: dataList[0].color,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '${dataList[0].value.toInt()}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                      '%' + s0,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  //Map<String, double> dataMap, List<Color> colorList,BuildContext context
  Widget _buildChart(List<CircularSegmentEntry> dataList) {
    _totalCount = _findTotalCount(dataList);
    s1 = _createText("TOPLAMDA", 20, Colors.grey[600], false);
    s1 = _createText("TALEP", 20, Colors.grey[600], false);
    total = _createText('$_totalCount', 24, Colors.black87, true);
    return Container(
      child: AnimatedCircularChart(
        size: Size(500, 250),
        initialChartData: <CircularStackEntry>[
          CircularStackEntry(
            <CircularSegmentEntry>[
              dataList[0],
              dataList[1],
            ],
          ),
        ],
        chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
        startAngle: -90,
        holeRadius: 25,
        holeLabel:
            "TOPLAMDA \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t $_totalCount \n\t\t\t TALEP", // $s1 \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t $total \n\t\t\t $s2
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTitleBar(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .247,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                bottom: Radius.circular(25),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.assessment,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Genel Durum",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 28,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _createText(String msg, double size, Color color, bool isBold) {
  return Text(
    msg,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: color,
      fontSize: size,
      fontWeight: isBold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
    ),
  );
}

int _findTotalCount(List<CircularSegmentEntry> dataList) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
    result += (dataList[i].value).toInt();
  }
  return result;
}

List<CircularSegmentEntry> _loadData() {
  List<CircularSegmentEntry> dataList = [];
  CircularSegmentEntry chartData1 =
      new CircularSegmentEntry(150, Colors.greenAccent, rankKey: 'Sonuçlanan');
  CircularSegmentEntry chartData2 =
      new CircularSegmentEntry(150, Colors.blue, rankKey: 'İşlemde');
  dataList.add(chartData1);
  dataList.add(chartData2);
  return dataList;
}
```

**Extra question: If is there any thing that I can do for a more efficient design, can you tell me that ? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this happening because of this piece of code in your Stack. This Container take your full screen size. that's why your GridView item build immediate after screen size. Try to remove this Container or reduce the height of it.

```
Container(
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   ),
```

**UPDATE:**
You can try this. I have not tried this but Maybe this will help

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: _buildTitleBar(context),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: _buildCard(context),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

Comment: When I tried this, my title bar and my card widget got stuck in the top of screen, so If I get rid of that container I should change something else in the stack. I'll wait for your idea meanwhile I am going to try positioned widget for the stack

Comment: you can use Container instead of Position. and give some margin to top. And also wrap that container with Align and make the alignment topCenter. I'm not testing this as well as your code. but the main problem here is your container which has the height of the whole screen.

Comment: What about If I wrap my gridview widget and card widget with a container in order to line them up vertically. If so how can I build my screen again cause my card wont show further the titlebar widget.

Comment: @TahaAteş I have added a piece of code. Please try that. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I used your solution and It worked but there's a little bit problem again, how can I daw gridview widget closer to my card widget ? I couldn't figured it out because these two widgets are in a column widget and I want to draw them a little bit closer. Even that I have exact number 15px.